# How can I set enhancedCPC on TargetSpendBiddingScheme via the API

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I am using v201607 java library and I tried to set enhancedCPC on TargetSpendBiddingScheme via the API but I couldn't find that field on 
TargetSpendBiddingScheme object. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, setting the enhanced CPC option for TARGET_SPEND is not supported at this time in the AdWords API. 
I got a answer from Google.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/adwords-api/R5TjRit6Yrc